# Inline declarations: var vs const

Tags: delphi, constants, inline-variable

When I use inline declarations, should I prefer `const` over `var`?

In all online examples, and even in Delphi's own documentation, I see that `var` is being used. However, I think that `const` often better expresses my intentions, and prevents accidental modifications.

Small example to demonstrate what I mean:

```
{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}

program VarVsConst;

uses
  Spring.Collections,
  System.SysUtils;

function UsingVar:string;
begin
  var dict := TCollections.CreateDictionary<string, Integer>;
  dict.Add ('one', 1);
  var pair := dict.ExtractPair('one');
  Result := pair.Value.ToString;
end;

function UsingConst:string;
begin
  const dict = TCollections.CreateDictionary<string, Integer>;
  dict.Add ('one', 1);
  const pair = dict.ExtractPair('one');
  Result := pair.Value.ToString;
end;

begin
  Writeln(UsingVar);
  Writeln(UsingConst);
  Readln;
end.
```

So, are there any downsides or dangers to the `UsingConst` implementation?

Comment: No, feel free to use `const` whenever possible.

Comment: If you need a constant, use `const`. If you need a variable, use `var`.

Comment: @RemyLebeau: haha, creative answer! :D Can I translate your comment to: "there are no gotchas when using inline constants"?

Comment: @WoutervanNifterick: Yes, that would be a correct statement.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose a downside could be that a program is more easily "hacked" into.  It's a static value.  Not sure how much more of a downside when you've got a var assignment like str := 'password' but you get the idea, this is more of an "in general" const opinion.  In your example I really don't see a difference as far as this goes, but there are people smarter than me who could spot it if there.

I like const, once it's assigned you can't fubar things accidentally.  If I'm that worried about a hack I can change things after the fact, closer to release.

Comment: I'm afraid I don't see your point. Besides, a `const X := TMyObject.Create` doesn't make the object `X` points to immutable at all (but the `X` pointer cannot be changed).

Comment: The generated code is identical between the two versions. The constness is compiler enforced. Potential for hacking is not an issue at all.

Comment: To me, this question could be viewed two ways.  One, in my specific example, are there any downsides.  Or two, as a general rule, are there any downsides to using const vs var.   I mean, he does ask the question both ways at beginning and end.  I think your comments are spot on and agree with you in regards to his example.  Hence why I said "in your example I don't see much of a difference" but I think I wasn't clear enough on that. Using const in a dynamic memory allocation is much safer, than say using const UserName = "Fred".

Comment: A last comment, this was not meant as a problem with Delphi, but more of a programming in general thought, so it may or may not apply in a specific forum to a language.  Unfortunately in today's world, ransomware is always out there lurking in the shadows.  I've been writing software for a long long time, not that it makes me smarter or better than anybody, it's just what I love to do. What I detest most of all is how I have to play security cop more and more these days.  I miss the old days of just solving problems and making things faster and more efficient.

Comment: This seems like an argument against careless use of string literals, not an argument for var over const.
It is clear that having 'SuperSecretPass' in your source is not good in any case.